# vscode debugging with react+babel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, vscode-debugger

I have a project which these scripts:

- "dev": "babel-node --presets 'react,es2015' src/server.js"
- "start": "NODE_ENV=development babel-node --presets 'react,es2015' src/server.js"
- "build": "NODE_ENV=development webpack -p"

I want to know how launch.json should be wrote to debug with VScode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `debugger;` statement, you can set it in your code and when you will run the app, automatically will get in a debug mode on the Browser.

Please read about debugger statement on the link below
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_debugger.asp